# Build child module without building parent module when version of all modules are driven by a single property

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

I have a multi module project with below hierarchy :

`parent-build` project pom.xml

```
...
    <groupId>com.my.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-build</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>parent-build</name>
    <version>${version.product}</version>
    <properties>
        <version.product>1.0</version.product>
    </properties>
    ...
```

`build-all` project pom.xml

```
...
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent-build</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.my.project</groupId>
        <version>${version.product}</version>
        <relativePath>../parent-build/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.my.project</groupId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>../child-1</module>
        <module>../child-2</module>
    </modules>
    ...
```

`child-2` project pom.xml

```
...
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent-build</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.my.project</groupId>
        <version>${version.product}</version>
        <relativePath>../parent-build/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.my.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>child-2</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>${version.product}</version>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>child-1</artifactId>
            <version>${version.product}</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
    ...
```

`child-1` project pom.xml

```
...
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent-build</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.my.project</groupId>
        <version>${version.product}</version>
        <relativePath>../parent-build/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.my.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>child-1</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>${version.product}</version>
    ...
```

I want to build all jars with same version and this version should be specified at single place.
I declared a property in parent-build pom.xml

Now when I do `mvn clean install` on build-all project , it builds all projects in specified order of modules.
That is fine.

But in some cases , I want to build `child-2` project only.

i.e ,lets say I do some changes in child-2 project and want to build only this project.
The problem with this scenario is , it cannot find the property value `version.product`

Edit:

Below is the error I am getting when building child-2 project

```
Could not transfer artifact com.my.project:parent-build:pom:${version.product} from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Illegal character in path at index 66: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/my/project/parent-build/${version.product}/parent-build-${version.product}.pom
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe child modules automatically inherit the version of their parent, so you don't have to explicitly declare it.

Comment: As already mentioned by luc14n0 the version of the parent is inherited. So the only location you need to write the version explicit is in the parent element. In the childs itself you should omit that. Furthermore the structure of your pom's shows that you didn't follow the sturcuture in your directories....which should be fixed cause that will simplify the pom file..you can remove the relativePath elements and you can simpifiy things like `<module>../child1</module>` into `<module>child1</module>`.. If you like to build a child alone you can call maven via `mvn -pl child1` from the root.

Comment: version.product property is picked by maven when I run build-all project.But when I build child-2 it cannot find a folder "version.product".Also I omitted versions from child pom itself. My actual scenario is something different and have around 25 child projects.Folder structure and relative paths are correct in my project. Mentioned projects are just a copy to show the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[flatten-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/examples/example-central-version.html)

This is what I want.

This plugin will replace your version specified in property, with actual property value in all effective pom.xml.

So later if you build any child separately, it will build successfully.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would urge against this, but I know you may have a module that is not working properly yet etc.  In the past I have used profiles in the parent pom to control the modules list:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>all</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>1</module>
            <module>2</module>
            <module>3</module>
            <module>4</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <modules>
            <module>1</module>
            <module>2</module>
            <module>3</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

then for :

1) mvn clean install  - you will get all modules

2) mvn clean install -Pprofile1 you will only get modules 1,2 & 3.

Comment: As per your solution,my requirement is to build child-3 only. I dont want to rebuild child-1 and child-2. As their jars are already in m2 directory.

Comment: @akash777.sharma I think you're saying this is just what you need then??   I would be careful using this as more than an interim solution.  If the children are not part of this parent then perhaps split them into a separate parent.